# No puedo hacer que un div en React con Tailwind ocupe todo el ancho de la página

Tags: reactjs, div, tailwind, footer

Estoy intentando que el div ocupe todo el ancho de la página, con el siguiente código:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Footer = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <footer className="footer bg-blue-700 max-w-full mx-auto h-20">
          <p className="text-blue-700"></p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </>
  );

}

export default Footer;
```

Pero no resulta, me queda siempre un espacio en blanco a la derecha. En tailwind.config.js lo tengo así:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
      serif: ['Merriweather', 'serif'],
      poppins: ['Poppins', 'sans-serif;'],
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        mytheme: {
          primary: '#4060ab',
          secondary: '#646FD4',
          accent: '#FFD24C',
          neutral: '#3D4451',
          'base-100': '#FFFFFF',
          info: '#3ABFF8',
          success: '#36D399',
          warning: '#FBBD23',
          error: '#F87272',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  variant: {},
  maxWidth: {
    '1/4': '25%',
    '1/2': '50%',
    '3/4': '75%',
    'full': '100%',
    'screen': '1920px',
  },
  plugins: [require('daisyui'), require('tw-elements/dist/plugin')],
};
```

Y la página queda así (el div de arriba lo logré modificando el margin, pero como quiero que el footer ocupe todo el ancho, el margin no me sirve)

[image: Imagen de como queda el footer con un espacio en blanco al lado izquierdo]

He intentado aplicar hoja de estilos CSS pero siento que no se aplican los estilos, por lo que puede que lo esté haciendo mal o llamando mal al archivo CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes añadir `w-screen` en el **className** de `footer`.

Esta clase te permite usar el ancho de la pantalla

Docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#viewport-width

Comment: Gracias, amigo, había revisado la documentación pero no supe aplicar eso, lo hacía con w-full, por ejemplo. En efecto, tu respuesta solucionó de inmediato mi problema.